Finding the pivot distribution
I am having trouble with this exercise. It is given below.
Let it be X volume sample $n$ from the logistic distribution, with density $f(x;\theta,\sigma)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma}}}{\sigma(1+e^{-\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma}})^{2}}$, $x\in R$ where are both parameters $\theta \in R$ and $\sigma>0$ unknown.
In the case of a large $n$ determine $90%$ a confidence interval based on the asymptotic normal pivot distribution $Q$(use that $EX_{i}=\theta$).
In case $n$ is not large enough for the normal approximation, describe how to find the quantile of the unknown pivot distribution $Q$ that could be approximated by simulation.
My attempt:
I know that pivot is $Q=\frac{\overline{X}-\theta}{S}\sqrt{n}$. I wanted to use at first $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\theta)\to N(0, \frac{1}{I(\theta)})$. Than I got $I(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sigma}$. I than tried using delta method by $g(\theta)=\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}}}$. Now I get $\sqrt{n}(\frac{\overline{X}}{S}-\frac{\theta}{S})\to N(0, \frac{\sigma^{2}}{S^{2}})$. I realized that I should prove that the first approximation stands. I could say that $\Theta=(-\infty,\infty)$ is opened. I am having trouble proving that $f($x$;\theta)$ is three times differentiable. I got something for $1.$ differentiable that looks ugly. I am not sure that I am supposed to calculate all that. And when n is small I simply have no idea. Should I write R code for that or what should I do or say? This was my exam question. Thanks for all the help in advance.

of what do you want to construct a confidence interval?

I am so sorry. I need confidence interval for theta.

Why '$\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\theta)\to N(0, \frac{1}{I(\theta)})$'? You need the CLT here.

Thank you so much.
